# Is it possible to run the utility bar api and import a js file at the same time?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, aura, utility-bar

I have some html/js code I want to display in a utility bar item, and I want to be able to run the [Utility Bar API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_methods_lightning_utilityBarAPI.htm) on some events that occur in the js code. The html includes me importing a js file I am storing as a static resource.

The problem seems to be that:

- You can only run the utility bar api in an aura component
- You cannot use script tags in aura components

I was able to use `ltng:require` to include the static resource, but I couldn't access the code from the controller code (the static resource populates a property on the window object, which I couldn't access from the controller for some reason.

Am I missing something here? Is it possible to accomplish this? It seems strange that I wouldn't be able to.

Comment: ltng:require is the correct method; if you're having a problem with the static resource, it might be worth asking a separate question about it. In the general sense, you can indeed attach things to "window" and have them accessible in your main script.

Comment: Will ask another question but here is what is breaking: `var global = this; console.log(global.x);`. It breaks on the second line of code there.

Comment: It looks like this is because the code is executed in strict mode. (note: the lines of code i pasted are wrapped in an iffe)

Comment: Yes, scripts are always executed in strict mode. You may need to modify it to be strict-mode compatible, or find an alternative that is.

Comment: Unfortunately refactoring the library to use strict mode would be a big effort, and there are no other alternative libraries. Are there any workarounds here that you know of?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a non-strict environment to get this to work without refactoring the original script. In Aura, you could use a lightning:container or Visualforce page in an iframe to host the script. Some additional "boilerplate" code will be necessary to interface the script to the component.

Comment: Thanks for the options, but the visualforce page still ran in strict mode unfortunately, and the lightning:container didn't work either (unless if i am missing something). I posted a new question here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/355677/using-a-non-strict-javascript-library-in-an-aura-component